# how do POST API requests use parallel processing in python? requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:

Tags: python, api, post, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have code like this:

```
import requests
import multiprocessing as mp
import json
import time

BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/employees'

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    array = json.load(f)

def internet_resource_getter(post_data):
    stuff_got = []
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL, json=post_data)
    stuff_got.append(response.json())
    print(stuff_got)
    time.sleep(1)
    return stuff_got

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # freeze_support() here if program needs to be frozen  
    start=time.time()
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.map(internet_resource_getter, array)
    elapsed = (time.time() - start)  
    print("\n","time elapsed is :", elapsed)
```

in file data.json contains 500 records, for example:

```
[{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Swen"},{"first_name":"Ricard","last_name":"Candra"}]
```

in BASE_URL there is data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Sebastian",
    "last_name": "Eschweiler"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "last_name": "Palmer"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Ann",
    "last_name": "Smith"
  }
]
```

expected output after POST API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Sebastian",
    "last_name": "Eschweiler"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "last_name": "Palmer"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Ann",
    "last_name": "Smith"
  },
 {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Swen"
  },
{
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Ricard",
    "last_name": "Candra"
  },
]
```

with my code above, the data that enters the url is only 420 records, even though my data.json is 500 records. how do I solve this so that I post 500 records to url. I don’t know why only 400 data are processed.
I have an error like this:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paralel_pro.py", line 28, in <module>
    pool.map(internet_resource_getter, array)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: I wonder if all 500 entries in your dataset reproduce the same result.  If so, I would narrow down on your dataset and share with us some examples of the 80 that fail.  Bad data could explain a server suddenly disconnecting (if it doesn't gracefully handle a NullPointerException arising from unsanitized input, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your answer, check your server logs.  I suspect bad data and/or server not handling unexpected data gracefully.

### Client-Side Check

See if the 80 records are always the same 80 records.

### Server-Side Check

Can you find the logs for your server that is running on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/employees`?  It looks like it is running on your same machine.  The server's application or service logs should have the smoking gun.

Comment: if I reduce the number of processes by changing my code `with mp.Pool (3) as pool:` then  all my data is entered successfully. but my data is not sequential according to records in file  data.json

Comment: @irfan if 3 processes works 100% but 4 does not (20% error rate), that is very intriguing to me.  In any regard, this seems like a server-side issue to me as you can exceed even the process count (around 15-20 I think it can buckle on my macbook).  Does your server spawn a lot of processes?

Comment: So @Irfan, according to your comment here, your issue is resolved then?

Comment: I use the json server and I only use it to process my code above. But I wonder if I set time.sleep (0.2) and m.pool (3) or time.sleep (0.4) and m.pool (4), the connection error warning will appear as before. but if time.sleep (0.4) and m.pool (3), all data will be processed successfully.

Comment: So in my code the fastest process is only when time.sleep (0.4) and m.pool (3), the overall data is successfully processed. if I want to speed up by reducing time.sleep and increasing the value of the process then not all data is successfully processed